# how to fetch all images of a page?

Tags: php

i need two tools or scripts in php....

First i need a tool/php scriot that can fetch all the images of a given link of a page,so that i can store those images in my database for later on showing them as the link's thumbnail.

Second i need a tool/php script that can fetch title,description and snapshot thumbnail of the given link of a page.

How can i do so??
Any tool or any php script ??

EDIT:
I need something similar to Facebook's thing which you get when you tries to post a 'Link' on anyone's wall or so.

Comment: i tried parsing the things up but that's not worth i guess as i need only specific content,moreover evey page has different construction so thats why..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this tool is what you are looking for : http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ .
You have an example in the Quick Start to get all the images.

Edit :
Here is a tutorial if you want : http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/html-parsing-and-screen-scraping-with-the-simple-html-dom-library/

Another way to do it is to use the DOM and the classes included in PHP (doc : https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). And to fetch all the `meta` tags of your page you can do :

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('you_page.php');

$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

foreach ($metas as $meta)
{
    //To get a specific attribute
    echo $meta->getAttribute('your_attribute');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could  go with the current trends and use Node: [Scrape web pages in real time with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211486/scrape-web-pages-in-real-time-with-node-js)

Though if you're on Windows and Unix scares you it may be more trouble than it's worth.

Justin

Answer (score 0):

++ for SimpleHtmlDom

```
$ret = $html->find('a, img');
```

and to get title ,etc, you can use the same 
refer to the manual,

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

facebook doent't display the screen shot of the website, but a image which it thinks is relevant. They also follow the [opengraph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) protocol,

for example if your website has

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
```

meta tag , then it will use that image as the thumbnail for the wall post/ status.