# How do I fetch data from a website to further process or just show them with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

This question has to do mostly on how do I find the way to fetch them.

Let's say I have a website with olympic games displaying medals per country per game.

I have a website link http://www.olympic.org/content/results-and-medalists/searchresultpercountry/?athletename=&country=ger&sport2=&games2=&event2=&mengender=true&womengender=true&mixedgender=true&goldmedal=true&silvermedal=true&bronzemedal=true&worldrecord=true&olympicrecord=false&teamclassification=true&individualclassification=true&winter=true&summer=true

This displays the Germany's medals in every event. I want to retrieve the data as an array or something and display them in a table. The first thing I should do is open firebug and search for a json link to parse the data. The only time I have retrieved data from a website was by using twitter's or facebook's json data to show the followers and likes.

How do I find the way to retrieve them ? In the link I posted, how can I fetch data ?

Comment: Unless the originating website provides a data API of some sort you cannot retrieve the information as data.

Comment: You can use the `load` method to load via ajax this table (you must kwno the table id) and process it once you got it.

Comment: I have read many people that use a DOM parser. Is there something like that in JQuery or another JS library ?

Answer (score 0):

Try $.get
You can pass the callback function to use the data comes from the url specified and print it as you need.

```
$.get('http://www.yoursite.com/index.html', function(data) {
  $('content').html(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

Accordingly if the returned data is in jSon format then you can easily access all its elements  as well with ease.

Cheers

Comment: can you send a very very simple jsfiddle to see how it works ?

Comment: take a look at it.. We can use it via jQuery.load too in case of simple html.
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load

Comment: but this works for internal content. I want to be able to parse data using websites' links. How do I read another website's data to retrieve the DOM elements that I want? For example I want to retrieve what <span id="ctl00_mainContent_rptSearchResults_ctl00_MedalistSearchBlock_rptSearchResults_ctl03_sportLabel"> </span> displays from the link I posted.

Comment: It can't with pure jQuery or JavaScript because you can't fetch content from domains different from the one the script is running from. However as a workaround you can get this done with the help of jQuery using IFrame. Set the IFrame URL and get its content after loading using jQuery. Cheers

Comment: But how did I fetch content from twitter and facebook ? Is this because they have public APIs ? This means I must find a public API of the olympic games in order to access their data from my website ?

Answer (score 0):

If the site does not provide public API you cannot get their content with pure Ajax. But nevertheless you can get the content by [web scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping). F.ex., you can get the page content by PHP script, extract the data you need from HTML, format it to JSON or XML and pass it to your Ajax request.

Take a look at an example [here](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.dk/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html) and at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947/how-to-implement-a-web-scraper-in-php) question.

Comment: I have been asked to fetch some data from a website that does not have any public API with any Javascript library. This is to be done as an exercise and I am seeking ways to develop this. If you can't fetch a website's data from the span ids using js then there is no meaning. It's easy to complete this in PHP but the exercise says only HTML5 & any JS library.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211486/scrape-web-pages-in-real-time-with-node-js